# Как сделать 301 редирект .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

У меня есть url:

```
/en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage%E2%80%8B
```

Я пробую сделать редирект

```
Redirect 301 /en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage\%E2\%80\%8B /en
```

или так

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+ /en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage%E2%80%8B
RewriteRule ^ /en [R=301,L]
```

Не работает. Как я могу выполнить редирект с url в котором есть знак `%`?

Comment: Каталог /en начинается от корня сайта? .htaccess лежит в корне сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не `%E2%80%8B`, а `\xE2\x80\x8B`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \xE2\x80\x8B http://google.com/ [R,L]
```